# Color Profile Proof - Deep Blacks with simulated paper color?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, cmyk, color-profile, proofing

I am not entirely new to graphics design in general, but this is the first time I will send my work off to a professional printing business working with the following details:

- FOGRA39 (ISO Coated v2)
- Ink coverage limits of 300% (theoritical limit 330%)

Enabling color proofing in Adobe InDesign **with** simulated paper color on the mentioned profile, the deepest black I can achieve is this black: 78,68,58,94, giving me a coverage of 298%. **However**, my color proofing (softproof) looks very "flat", more like a medium grey color.

My monitor is not specifically for graphic design, so how do I check whether my final print (from the offset printers) will look?

**Is it possible that paper color simulation is inaccurate, and the softproof is lighter than the actual print?**

Comment: If your monitor is not calibrated or profiled with a hardware tool (colorimeter like colormunki for example) then nothing on your screen is even remotely accurate.

Comment: Hi there. I just checked and believe it has been manually calibrated. I even have a calibration report from Dell, it's a U2515H. Windows also shows me that I am using the color profile from that exact monitor, so I assume that it is calibrated?

Comment: Factry calibration means nothing as the calibration should be done quite often at your deskside illumination. Unless you or somebody you know calibrated with a calibrated your monitor then it is not calibrated. There is more to calibration that can not be done in the factory, such as what the light conditions are a your desk righ now. It is thus safe to assume that your not calibrated and anything you see is inaccurate.

Comment: Thank you. I will buy a color calibration device and see where that gets me :)